# How to add more characters and letters to rot13 and Caesar encryption

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-symmetric, rot13

I want to add the letters "ç," "ğ," "ı," "ö" and "ü" into this encrypter's alphabet, and maybe special chars, too. How can I do that?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < metin.length(); i++) {
        char harf = metin.charAt(i);
        if       (harf >= 'a' && harf <= 'm') harf += i;
        else if  (harf >= 'A' && harf <= 'M') harf += i;
        else if  (harf >= 'n' && harf <= 'z') harf -= i;
        else if  (harf >= 'N' && harf <= 'Z') harf -= i;
        System.out.print(harf);
    }
```

Comment: This question is not about Java. Decide what you want your cipher to look like and the Java code to do it will be obvious.

Comment: That's not caesar or Rot13. It's not reversible(for `i == 1` `harf=='k'` and `harf=='n'` result in the same output) and it has no key. So it's not even encryption.

Comment: rot13 used for 26 letters, you will have 31 letters, 31 is not even.

Comment: I only want to know how to expanding this alphabets with this algorithm. Is it possible or not? But i've got my answers so thanks for your "supportive" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the strategy more general like this.

```
String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!$%^&*()äöü";

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char ch = text.charAt(i);
    ch--;
    if (ch % 32 < 13)
        ch += 13;
    else if (ch % 32 < 26)
        ch -= 13;
    else if (ch % 32 < 29)
        ch += 3;
    else
        ch -= 3;
    ch++;
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```

prints

```
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm#$%&'()*+,.12[3756ñéÿ
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Java intern Char's as ints to implement the cipher.
A better way would be to use a `String charSet = "abcdefgh.... %&/(öäüô";` with the chars you want in you charSet.

```
String charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöü";    
for (int i = 0; i < metin.length(); i++) {
    int j = charset.indexOf(metin.charAt(i));
    if(j < -1)
    {
        //deal with unknown char
    }
    if(j == charset.length)
    {
        j=0;
    }
    System.out.print(charset.charAt(j+1);
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: For any practical usage this is horribly inefficient. See Peter Lawrey's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379261/18573) below for a much better approach.